# Update app on system_ext partition Android AOSP

Tags: android, adb, android-source

I'm learning about AOSP and I've made a Service.apk and placed it in the system_ext/priv-app partition. For the first time, I've to build a full Android image including my service and flash to the device and it works as expected. But now when I want to update my TestService.apk I can't push it into the system_ext partition via $adb push, the log says:

failed to copy 'TestService.apk' to '/system_ext/priv-app/TestService/TestService.apk': couldn't create file: Read-only file system

And I've also tried to use $adb install the result still failed:
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package com.testservice is a persistent app. Persistent apps are not updateable.]

Comment: System partition(s) are by default mounted read-only. If you have root access on that rom you can try to remount the partition r/w and then replace the APK file in file-system.